# Add column to count number of sub values under main value

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have a dataset example as below and would like to add an extra column that will show the number of subblocks in a block in the example further down.

I have played around with rown_number but have been unsuccessful.
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY BlockRef,SubBlockRef ORDER BY BlockRef, SubBlockRef DESC)

```
BlockRef    Blocks  SubBlockRef SubBlocks
37391   BLOCK   49391   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49391   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49391   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49391   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49391   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49391   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49392   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49392   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49392   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49392   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49392   SUBB
37391   BLOCK   49392   SUBB
```

[image]

Any help appreciated

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct)` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       count(distinct SubBlockRef) over (partition by BlockRef) as num_subblocks
from t;
```

Although standard functionality, not all databases support `distinct` in window functions.  There is a simple workaround using `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       ( dense_rank() over (partition by BlockRef order by SubBlockRef) +
         dense_rank() over (partition by BlockRef order by SubBlockRef desc) - 1
       ) as num_subblocks
from t;
```

Given that there is such a simple work-around, it is surprising that many databases do not support the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your input Gordon 
Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.

Comment: Dense rank does not allow any arguments

Comment: almost there, it is now counting to 3, it is adding 1+2 but should be 2.

Comment: @user3306489 . . . The `dense_rank()` method is one more than the distinct count, so "1" needs to be subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join as follows:

```
select t.*,
       Tt.cnt as num_subblocks
  from your_table t
  Join (select BlockRef, count(distinct SubBlockRef) as cnt
         From your_table 
        Group by BlockRef) tt
   On tt.BlockRef = t.BlockRef
```

Comment: Thanks @popeye that was my backup solution but was trying to avoid creating a subquery.